# nodeJs usb-Detection library is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, usb

I'm trying to use the usb-detection library for Node.js to write an txt file where the product-Id and the vendor-Id is written, for some reason my code is not working and I don't know why, thanks for the help

```
var fs = require('fs')
var usbDetect = require('usb-detection')

usbDetect.startMonitoring();

console.log("Listening for USB-Sticks...")
console.log("Press Ctrl+C to exit")
usbDetect.on('change:vid:pid', function(device) { console.log('change', device); });

    usbDetect.on('add:vid:pid', function(device) { 
        console.log("USB-Stick detected")
        var string = "USB-Stick name: "+ device.serialNumber +""+
                    "vendorId: "+ device.vendorId +""+
                    "productId: "+ device.productId +"\n"

        fs.writeFile("Output.txt", string, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: does it returning any errors or logs?